# `make install` on a module, I get `pgxs.mk:114: recipe for target 'install' failed`

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, errors, postgresql-extensions

I'm trying to install a PostgreSQL module ([`pg-bignum`](https://github.com/beargiles/pg-bignum)). When I try `make install`, I get the following at the bottom of the log

```
/usr/bin/install: will not overwrite just-created '/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/bignum--0.8.0.sql' with './/sql/bignum--0.8.0.sql'
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk:114: recipe for 
target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Currently using PostgreSQL-9.5 and Ubuntu.

Comment: When I see that, there is usually further up the log that says why it failed.  (Often because it needs root access to do the installation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a problem with the `pg-bignum`'s Makefile. [Filed upstream here](https://github.com/beargiles/pg-bignum/issues/2).